# I can’t use cordova plugins

Tags: cordova

I want to use `$cordovaContacts`.
I created an app with ionic. Then I copied '`ng-cordova.min.js`' to '`www`' folder. And I called it in my 'index.html'.
Then I copied `http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/contacts/` to my controller js file.

Then I copied this code to my app js file, too :

```
    angular.module('ngCordova.plugins.contacts', [])

  .factory('$cordovaContacts', ['$q', function ($q) {

    return {
      save: function (contact) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var deviceContact = navigator.contacts.create(contact);

        deviceContact.save(function (result) {
          q.resolve(result);
        }, function (err) {
          q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
      },

      remove: function (contact) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var deviceContact = navigator.contacts.create(contact);

        deviceContact.remove(function (result) {
          q.resolve(result);
        }, function (err) {
          q.reject(err);
        });
        return q.promise;
      },

      clone: function (contact) {
        var deviceContact = navigator.contacts.create(contact);
        return deviceContact.clone(contact);
      },

      find: function (options) {
        var q = $q.defer();
        var fields = options.fields || ['id', 'displayName'];
        delete options.fields;
        if (Object.keys(options).length === 0) {
          navigator.contacts.find(fields, function (results) {
            q.resolve(results);
          },function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
          });
        }
        else {
          navigator.contacts.find(fields, function (results) {
            q.resolve(results);
          }, function (err) {
            q.reject(err);
          }, options);
        }
        return q.promise;
      },

      pickContact: function () {
        var q = $q.defer();

        navigator.contacts.pickContact(function (contact) {
          q.resolve(contact);
        }, function (err) {
          q.reject(err);
        });

        return q.promise;
      }

      // TODO: method to set / get ContactAddress
      // TODO: method to set / get ContactError
      // TODO: method to set / get ContactField
      // TODO: method to set / get ContactName
      // TODO: method to set / get ContactOrganization
    };
  }]);
```

Finally I wrote this code:

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
{{contact.name}}
</ion-item>
```

But it doesn't work on my android device. (I didn't try on another device. I don't need the others now.)

And console error:

[image]:

I researched on the internet. But I can't use any cordova or ionic plugin. I am new, sorry for English.

Comment: You don't need to add Cordova.min.js, Ionic build process will add itself. Post the error which you are getting

Comment: Have you added cordova-plugin-contacts to your project?

Comment: @Anjana-Systematix yes I've add plugin to my project.

Comment: @Nitishkumar Singh I have already added it.

Comment: you are debugging it on device or browser? can you list the plugins installed in your project?

Comment: I reinstalled everything and it happened